# Where is Golem keeping track of files

Tags: r, golem

I'm getting to grips with Golem in R and ran across something which I don't quite understand.
So I wanted to try a different UI, so I saved my Shinydashboard UI as app_UI_dash.R and wrote a new app_UI.R file using shinymaterial.

But when I ran run_dev.R I expected to see my Material version, but instead I saw my original shiny dashboard version.

Modifications to app_UI_dash.R were reflected in the output, so clearly Golem is still building from that file.
Why did this happen, and how do I control which R file Golem is using as it's UI file?

Comment: Hi, can you put a sample of your app_UI? It is in this file that the UI of your module must be called.